# spark client cannot find spark.Spark class

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm a newbie to Spark.  I spun up an Apache Spark AMI on AWS, added Maven 3, then started a master on 7077. I then ran mvn package on the spark-basic-structure demo app from sparkjava.com which generated spark-basic-structure-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.

I used this command to run it

spark-submit --class "app.Application" --master spark://ip-172-31-29-154:7077 spark-basic-structure-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

but got a class not found

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: spark.Spark

I can fix this by explicitly putting spark-core-2.7.1.jar in the --jars argument but shouldn't that be picked up in my repo?  Caveat: I don't know Maven that well.

Once "fixed" I then get another class not found

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler

my PATH is /usr/share/maven/bin:/home/ubuntu/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/share/sbt-launcher-packaging/bin/sbt-launch.jar/bin:/usr/lib/spark/bin:/usr/lib/spark/sbin

Not sure what I am missing.